# Spheroidal (elliptical) waves: a boundary problem

Tags: electromagnetism, differential-equations, spherical-harmonics

I'm trying to solve a boundary problem. I have known EM waves, which "bounce" of a charged, rotating oblate spheroid (ellipsoid).

Now the formulation of the boundary problem is not so hard, although the equations are complicated. My problem is I am not sure what shape the refracting ("bounced off") wave would take. Intuition says that the refracting wave would take on the shape of the object it bounces off, but I don't know how to describe these waves mathematically.
The incident waves are described in terms of vector spherical harmonics. Are there similar functions in [oblate spheroidal coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oblate_spheroidal_coordinates)? And can these functions be expressed in spherical coordinates?

Comment: Perhaps the [oblate spheroidal harmonics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oblate_spheroidal_coordinates#Oblate_spheroidal_harmonics) are what you're looking for?